VBA OUTLOOK CODE organize default folder sub folder
I am looking to organize a default folders sub folder but i cant seem to get the coding right, can someone please take a look at it?
FOLDER Structure
Sub OrganizeEmailsBySender()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim olBackupFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim olBackupEnd2022Folder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim olMail As Outlook.mailItem
    Dim olItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim olSenderFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim olSenderName As String
    Dim olItem As Object
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Initialize Outlook application and namespace
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set olNamespace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    ' Specify the default folder and the BACKUP END 2022 folder within it
    Set olBackup = olNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderBACKUP)
    Set olBackupEnd2022 = olBackup.Folders("BACKUP END 2022")
    Set olItems = olBackupEnd2022Folder.Items
    
    ' Loop through each email in the BACKUP END 2022 folder
    For i = olItems.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set olItem = olItems(i)
        
        ' Check if the item is a mail item
        If TypeOf olItem Is Outlook.mailItem Then
            Set olMail = olItem
            olSenderName = olMail.SenderName
            
            ' Check if a folder for the sender already exists
            On Error Resume Next
            Set olSenderFolder = olBackupEnd2022Folder.Folders(olSenderName)
            On Error GoTo 0
            
            ' If the folder does not exist, create it
            If olSenderFolder Is Nothing Then
                Set olSenderFolder = olBackupEnd2022Folder.Folders.Add(olSenderName)
            End If
            
            ' Move the email to the sender's folder
            olMail.Move olSenderFolder
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Clean up
    Set olMail = Nothing
    Set olItems = Nothing
    Set olInbox = Nothing
    Set olBackupFolder = Nothing
    Set olBackupEnd2022Folder = Nothing
    Set olSenderFolder = Nothing
    Set olNamespace = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "Emails have been organized by sender's name.", vbInformation
End Sub

Getting an OBJECT REQUIRED error on
Set olBackupEnd2022 = olBackup.Folders("BACKUP END 2022")


In the attached photo "Folder Structure" a Default folder is backup and has subfolders "Backup End 2022"

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.oldefaultfolders   GetDefaultFolder is for "built-in" folders - just use the name of the folder "BACKUP" as you do for other fodlers.

There is no olFolderBACKUP enum in the Outlook Object Model. The only available values are listed at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.oldefaultfolders
It would be a good idea to use Option Explicit in your code to prevent VB run-time from allowing to use undeclared variables and constants. Otherwise undeclared olFolderBACKUP would be defaulted to 0.
In your particular case, to open a folder by name on the same level as your default Inbox folder, you can use either
Set olBackup = olNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("BACKUP")

or
Set olBackup = olNamespace.DefaultStore.GetRootFolder.Folders("BACKUP")

